# Change all divs with class to fit div with most content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

this was a bit hard to explain but I will try.

Is there an easy way to set the width of all divs with the same class to the width of the one with most content.

Example if I have three divs with the same class I want them all to have the width of the one with the biggest width:

```
+------------+
|asddasadsdsa|
+------------+
|asdadsdsas  |
+------------+
|            |
+------------+
```

or like this:

```
+---------+
|asd      |
+---------+
|         |
+---------+
|adsaaaaaa|
+---------+
```

Kind of a table, but in my case the divs are spread out in different lists.

Comment: Just use `<table>` and don't over complicate the things :)

Comment: Please post the code that you have tried so far.

Comment: @VisioN Read the last line.

Comment: @JamesMontagne I've read. And yes my comment is in place. Table element should be much easier to embed than manipulate that bunch of divs, styles and possibly JS fixes.

Comment: what do you mean they are spread out in different lists? please post the html markup

Comment: @VisioN  Maybe I misread, but I take the last line to mean that these are divs spread throughout the document making it impossible to put them into a single table.

Comment: Yes, like @JamesMontagne says. As seen in the answers this seems to be a question of Javascript. I was hoping for an elegant CSS fix.

Comment: @nilsi CSS fix is `display: table` and `display: table-cell`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[There's a method for that](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max)....

```
var wid = 0;
$('.yourclass').each(function() {
    wid = Math.max($(this).width(),wid);
}).width(wid);
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply loop through all div's, collect the widest width and after all set it to your class:

```
var maxWidth = 0;
$('.yourclass').each(function() {
    maxWidth = Math.max(maxWidth, $(this).width());
}).width(maxWidth);
```

Comment: why not simply `maxWidth = Math.max (maxWidth, $(this).width());` in the function?

Answer (score 1):

Another variant:

```
var widths = [];
$('div')
    .each(function() { widths.push($(this).width()); })
    .width(Math.max.apply(null, widths));
```

Comment: I think your `null` is out of place.  I think you meant that to be the `thisArg` of `apply`.  As it is now, you're passing it to width.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this -

```
var biggiWidth = 0;

$('.class').each(function(){
  biggiWidth = $(this).width() > biggiWidth ? $(this).width() : biggiWidth;
});

$('.class').width(biggiWidth);
```

Answer (score 0):

Once I tried using css.

```
$('.class').css({"width": "auto", "white-space": "nowrap"});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to be different...

```
var maxWidth = Math.max.apply(null, $("div").map(function(){
    return $(this).width();
}));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rEBrF/1/